# OpenVPN will not connect from GUI on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: network-manager

New install of Ubuntu 18.04. No wired connection, wifi only.
Installed OpenVPN, Imported several ovpn files from my VPN provider.

When turning on VPN from the Network GUI a second wifi icon flashes and Ubuntu says "Connect failed"

I tried starting OpenVPN from the command line and that worked.  I verified that my Internet IP was the VPN.  So my VPN service is working through the firewall, wifi and my router but only from the command line.

The problem appears to be that the OpenVPN GUI (or the Ubuntu VPN GUI activated through the Ubuntu network settings page) is not attaching to the wifi.  This used to work with my old Ubuntu install (also 18.04).

How do I tell OpenVPN to the use the wifi?

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, it seems the Ubuntu settings app does not show all config options. This solved it for me, an alternative GUI which allows more settings. Although this is on newer versions of Ubuntu, I don't know 100% if this is installed with 18.04 or available to be installed but try it:

- Run `nm-connection-editor`
- Highlight your connection
- Click the cog icon
- Go to `General` tab
- Check `Automatically connect to VPN`
- Choose the VPN connection you want from the list.
- Click `Save`

Now disconnect/re-connect to your connection. Now each time you connect to that connection it should attempt to connect to the chosen VPN.

Only issue I have is that the network connection/vpn is not automatically restored when I resume from suspend. I have to manually connect to my network. I don't know if that can be solved, I have not looked into it yet.

Comment: I tried that and ubuntu went into a hard loop trying to connect to the VPN by default.  I had to hard restart the computer to stop it.  I think that this is definitely a network management issue or somehow I installed OpenVPN wrong.   BTW I looked in etc/openvpn and there are no .config files there.  Is that normal?

Comment: @BruceTripp all I did was import (Nord VPN in my case) .opvpn files via the network settings GUI and then did the nm-connection-editor tweak. It works for me on both wireless and wired. And I don't have anything in /etc/openvpn apart from `update-resolv-conf` script and empty `client` and server` directories. I think you will have to look at logs to see exactly what's happening around your `Connect failed` error.